# Best way to redirect a bad-rated domain to a new one?

Tags: domain, redirect, 301-redirect, seo

I recently bought a domain that has an Alexa rank of ~50000. However the domain has a poor history as the previous owner didn't responded to abuse emails nor any DMCA notices. Long story short, the domain is blacklisted in many places including google search. The site however is perfectly legal and I intend to start fresh on a new domain name.

I was curious whether a 301 redirect to new domain will also impact its rating being associated with the old one? Or a 302 (temp) redirect is a better choice? Or maybe even a 302 redirect to a third intermediate domain followed by a 301 redirect to my final domain?

EDIT: I don't care about reputation of the old domain (the one I bought). I just want to be sure that it won't affect my new (brand new) domain's reputation in any way.

Comment: If you want to start fresh, why would you redirect? Seems like it's not worth the risk.

Answer (score 0):

You can either ask your domain registrar to submit a blacklist removal request wherever site is blacklisted or you can also submit the request from your end . Make sure you will write a proper and valid reason for removal. Refer this link and check your website listing first [Click Here](https://sendgrid.com/blog/blacklisted-check-7-popular-blacklists-keep-reputation-intact/)

You will find a removal option there on each site, For e.g. [Barracudda](http://www.barracudacentral.org/rbl/removal-request)